# Can I use a colon in the id attribute in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need help with something. I found a code sample that does not fully understand. Can I use a colon in the id attribute?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Customer:Name" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very well documented on the official site, but there are certain types of punctuation that are allowed as part of the ID in a layout XML file, including semi-colons and periods. However, when you actually reference these ids in Java code, they are converted to underscores. Thus something like this:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/customer.name"/>
```

Is referenced in java code like this:

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.customer_name);
```

It's legal (not an error) to do so, but it isn't a good practice, because it makes searching for the ID more difficult.